# Why is spatial tensor called spatial?

Tags: soft-question, operator-algebras

I am reading Blackadar's book on operator algebras, and came upon the notion of *spatial tensor product* of $C^*$-algebras. It turns out to be the same as the *minimal tensor product*. To me, the term ''minimal'' makes sense. But why is it called ''spatial'' in the first place? What is the ''space'' being alluded to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you represent your C*-algebras faithfully on Hilbert spaces, say $A \subseteq B(H), B \subseteq B(K)$, the spatial/minimal tensor product is just the norm closure of algebraic tensor product $A \odot B \subseteq B(H \otimes K)$. In my mind, this is why its called spatial - it is defined as some algebra of operators on the underlying Hilbert space $H \otimes K$. It just so happens that the resulting C*-algebra is independent of the choices of faithful representations and so you have "the" spatial tensor product or "the" minimal tensor product.

Comment: Blackadar defines the minimal tensor as $||\sum_ja_j\otimes b_j||_{min}=\sup ||\sum_j \pi_A(a_j)\otimes \pi_B(b_j)||$ over all representations $\pi_A$ and $\pi_B$ of $A$ and $B$ respectively. Is this equivalent to the formulation you presented? It's not immediately obvious to me, unfortunately, and I can't seem to find a reference for it.